# Adding trace dynamically in plotly r shiny app

Tags: r, shiny, plotly

I am trying to add a plot in r shiny app using plotly. I can add it when I add the traces manually. But now I want to add the traces dynamically. Also I dont want to add traces for all columns. I just want to add traces for columns which end with sale. Below is the code so far. This doesnt add all the traces. How can I add all the traces which just which have `_sales` in them.

```
output$pacingplot <- renderPlotly({

  colNames <- names(Delivery_data)[-1] #Assuming Date is the first column

  print(colNames)
  p <- plotly::plot_ly(x = ~Delivery_data$Date, type = "scatter",
                       mode = "lines")
  for(trace in colNames){
    p <- p %>% plotly::add_trace(y = as.formula(paste0("~`", trace, "`")), name = trace)
  }

  p %>% 
    layout(title = "Impressions Over Time",
           xaxis = list(title = "Date"),
           yaxis = list (title = "Impressions"))


})
```

Below are the colnames (This doenst include date since I removed the first column):

```
[1] "apples_sales"           "apples_count"    "bananas_sales"          "bananas_count"   "oranges_sales"        "oranges_count" "peach_sales"          "peach_count"
```

Below is the data

```
Delivery_data <- data.frame(
  Date = c("2019-08-19", "2019-08-20", "2019-08-21",
           "2019-08-22", "2019-08-23", "2019-08-24"),
  apples_sales = c(10882.05495, 516.29755, 949.4084, 3950.5318,
                2034.02055, 1770.50415),
  apples_count = c(239575, 11281, 20150, 88679, 45672, 38553),
  peach_sales = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
  peach_count = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
  bananas_sales = c(9643.600102, 6041.538067, 5371.758106, 5238.308826,
              4994.43054, 5001.303585),
  bananas_count = c(630827, 510219, 565440, 576678, 518081, 551733),
  oranges_sales = c(0, 1694.44, 9105.89, 6179.47, 7366.31, 6275.43),
  oranges_count = c(0, 684210, 3695182, 2501560, 2984563, 2531400)
)
```

Comment: You should post a working example.

Comment: Just modified the question

Comment: Good on adding data. Do you want to put in code to create an `output` container? (You should also add a `library(plotly)` line.

Comment: Every person's pain point is different. I'm not a regular `plotly`-user, so the style of "create a function as a list-leaf" and then "use it" is not particularly natural. I would need a full use case, i.e. what to _do_ with that list item: `output$pacingplot`? When I throw your data at an empty list to which I add a "pacingplot"-element as an argument, I get: `Error in eval(expr, data, expr_env) : object 'apples_sales' not found`

Answer (score 2):

Like this it seems to work:

```
server <- function(input, output){
  output$pacingplot <- renderPlotly({

    colNames <- names(Delivery_data)[-1] #Assuming Date is the first column

    # subsetting on just _sales columns
    colNames <- colNames[grepl('_sales$', colNames)]
    print(colNames)

    # note that I added the data to the initial plot_ly call
    p <- plotly::plot_ly(data=Delivery_data, type = "scatter", mode = "lines")

    for(trace in colNames){
      p <- p %>% plotly::add_trace(x = ~as.Date(Date), # converted Date as date
                                   y = as.formula(paste0("~`", trace, "`")), name = trace)
    }

    p %>% 
      layout(title = "Impressions Over Time",
             xaxis = list(title = "Date"),
             yaxis = list (title = "Impressions"))
  })
}
```